# dbt snapshots: How to backfill from a table without updated_at/created_at timestamp?

Tags: dbt

We have several years worth of daily `SELECT * FROM source.table` captures for a given table.
We want to create a dbt snapshot that tracks row level changes over the set of daily captures.
The table does not have an updated_at field.

The perceived issue is that:

1. Given that the table does not have an created_at/updated_at field, we cannot use the dbt snapshot "timestamp" strategy;
2. Given that we have to backfill several years of daily captures on a first run, we think that we cannot use the "check" strategy, as our understanding is that the check strategy uses the time of execution to fill the `dbt_*` fields.

We could, in theory add the extraction timestamp as the updated_at field. However since our understanding of the "timestamp" strategy is that dbt only tracks the timestamp field, we assume that every record will have a new version for every capture we add to the dbt snapshot table. Is that a correct assessment?

Our best option at this time is to update manually the values in `dbt_*` fields to the extraction timestamps of our captures in storage in between every dbt snapshot run, and use the "check" strategy to determine changes.

Is there any dbt- native solution possible for this issue?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: I provided an answer for what I THINK you're trying to do. It would help if you could provide example source and target data, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have your own custom snapshot table being built, I wouldn't use DBT snapshots for this. I would just build a regular DBT transformation model using the existing snapshot table.

To consolidate the daily snapshots into one with only the modifications and effective timestamps, you can do something like this below. I'm assuming that your existing snapshot table is using `ID` + the `EXTRACTED_AT` timestamp as the PK, and `FIELD#` is whatever SCD attributes you're interested in tracking.

```
WITH DEDUPED AS (
    {# Only interested in records with attribute changes from the previously ingested version #}
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            LAG(FIELD1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY EXTRACTED_AT) PREVIOUS_FIELD1,
            LAG(FIELD2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY EXTRACTED_AT) PREVIOUS_FIELD2,
            ...
        FROM MY_TABLE
    )
    WHERE {{ dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(['FIELD1', 'FIELD2', ...]) }} != {{ dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(['PREVIOUS_FIELD1', 'PREVIOUS_FIELD2', ...]) }}
),
FINAL AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        FIELD1,
        FIELD2,
        ...,
        EXTRACTED_AT EFFECTIVE_START_AT,
        LEAD(EFFECTIVE_START_AT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_START_AT) EFFECTIVE_END_AT
    FROM DEDUPED
)

SELECT * FROM FINAL
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I'm not sure however we are on the same page with regards to the requirements - what I have is a set of daily `SELECT * FROM source.table_name` resultsets, not actual snapshots-as-defined-by-dbt that I am trying to squash together. Sorry for the confusion; what word would you use to refer to these?
(I'll edit the question to improve clarity)

Comment: If these daily resultsets are being stored in the same table, then it still sounds like they are snapshots...not DBT snapshots, like you said. But they are historical records of data at a point of time and the history of those records don't change. Is that correct?

Comment: They are not; they are in separate Cloud Storage objects. We were planning to loop through the objects in chronological order of date of creation, and apply dbt snapshot on each capture one at a time until the full history has been loaded.

Comment: Here's a suggested edit for your answer (should you choose to keep the same approach): https://pastebin.com/raw/xghbBcZy

If the new information provided makes it possible to use dbt snapshot instead of an incremental model, I am interested in learning about that solution as well!

Comment: I see what you mean...I don't think I would change my approach though. DBT snapshots are intended for cases where you don't have versioned data. In your case, you do. I think I would break this up into 2 models - 1 incremental model to load all of your versioned external source data and 1 using what I posted (which can also be an incremental model). If you're determined to us DBT snapshots, everything you posted in the OP sounds right to me. You'd have to create a one-time job to create the initial target snapshot table, then have DBT snapshot jobs take over incremental runs.

Comment: Thanks for your input Adam. I think the solution can be cost-optimized by (1) loading one capture per iteration alongside the previous iteration of the incremental model, (2) mark the capture's rows, (3) UNION the previous incremental model with the capture, (4) perform a similar operation as the one suggested in your answer. Here's a tentative implementation: https://pastebin.com/TNipAQkw